# jsr305_annotations Folder inside apk file

Tags: java, android, jsr305

I've had reports of problems with the installation of the apk.
I tried to extract the apk as a zip file and I found the folder
jsr305_annotations in the root APK
with inside
folder: v0_r47 -> file: V0_r47.gwt.xml
File: Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml

I would like information about those files and folders and a method to make sure that they are not included in my applications

thanks

Using
Eclipse
Version: 3.8.2
Build id: M20130131-0800

Android Development Toolkit
Version: 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705

Answer (score 0):

I'd seen those files included in an app as a result of including the library GoogleAdMobAdsSdk in a project (as available from here https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/)

If you open that JAR file you can see those annotations folders and XML files are present.

If you don't include that library directly, you may be including another JAR which has those files.
I'd suggest checking the JAR files you include in your project (by opening them in a file that can open APK/Zip files) to find which one(s) include the file and look for an alternative library.

Answer (score -1):

The javascript that comes with it looks like it will lock you out of your device and start making phone calls, mail, SMS, etc while it plays audio and shows a video. It also creates a *.css file and calls on varible `uri`. I didnt inspect every file but from the *.js file it dont look like I would want to run it. I found this in my Downloads folder, file name, "yourdownloadisready.apk", Im a tech. I cant imagine if a novice saw this.